# I need help to print the elements in this array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
 System.out.println("Here is the list by Category Type.");
 System.out.println("Please enter the category you are looking"
                  + " for.");
 String search = user_input.next();
 System.out.println("Here is what we found for that category: ");

 for (int row = 0; row < store.length; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < store[row].length; column++)
       if (store[row][column].toUpperCase().contains(search.toUpperCase()))
          System.out.println(String.format("%20s\t",store[row][column]));
```

**Here is my code to print out certain rows within the array but I get output that I don't want and I don't know how to go about doing this.** For example for the part that states

```
"Please enter the category you are looking for."
```

**I then enter:** school supplies, which has 6 elements that fall under that category and the output prints out like so.

**Here is what we found for that category:**

```
 School Supplies    
 School Supplies    
 School Supplies    
 School Supplies    
 School Supplies    
 School Supplies
```

I want to display the item as well not just the category.

Here is the array I am looking at.

```
 String[][] store = {       
        {"Alumni Drink ware", "Gifts", "$25.00"},
        {"Binders", "School Supplies", "$3.00"},
        {"Book bag", "School Supplies", "$20.00"},
        {"Fabulous Desserts", "Textbooks", "$25.00"},
        {"Folders", "School Supplies", "$1.00"},
        {"Gift Cards", "Gifts", "$25.00"},
        {"Highlighters", "School Supplies", "$2.00"},
        {"Jacket", "Campus Gear", "$65.00"},
        {"JAVA Programming", "Textbooks", "$150.00"},
        {"Network Solutions", "Textbooks", "$75.00"},
        {"Pencils", "School Supplies", "$1.00"},
        {"Pens", "School Supplies", "$2.00"},
        {"Shorts", "Campus Gear", "$10.00"},
        {"Sweatshirts", "Campus Gear", "$40.00"},
        {"T-shirts", "campus Gear", "$15.00"},
        {"Web Design Ideas", "Textbooks", "$55.00"}};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Here is the list by Category Type.");
System.out.println("Please enter the category you are looking"
              + " for.");
String search = user_input.next();
System.out.println("Here is what we found for that category: ");

for (int row = 0; row < store.length; row++) {
   for (int column = 0; column < store[row].length; column++)
   if (store[row][column].toUpperCase().contains(search.toUpperCase()))
      System.out.println(String.format("%20s\t", java.util.Arrays.toString(store[row])));
```